# Shiny - Clear inside the text when clicked on it

Tags: r, text, shiny, onclick, mouseevent

I am trying to make an Shiny app which takes input from user in textInput. I want text inside the textbox to be clear when it is clicked on. I could find solutions only for clicked on button. I need a mouse event for clicking on text box.

Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved through the shinyjs onclick function like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    useShinyjs(),
    
    fluidRow(
        textInput(inputId = "text_input", label = "Example Text Input", value = "Click me to clear")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    shinyjs::onclick(id = "text_input", expr = updateTextInput(inputId = "text_input", value = ""))
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked with a small edit.

shinyjs::onclick(id = "text_input", expr = updateTextInput(session, inputId = "text_input", value = ""))